# NStimer from NSThread

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nstimer, nsthread

iphone project.

How can i call NStimer from NSThread?

I tried with no luck.

Comment: This question is somewhat vague.  Can you provide some more information, or some sample code?

Comment: One that know about this problem, know what i writing about.

Answer (score 4):

Have you read the [NSTimer documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)?

Have you set up a run loop?

> Timers work in conjunction with run
>   loops. To use a timer effectively, you
>   should be aware of how run loops
>   operate

See the [Setting Up a Run Loop](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH15-SW25) section of the Threading Programming Guide.